# Create worksheetname of matrix in VLOOKUP-Function from Cell-Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I've got a working VLOOK-Function. The Matrix is on a different worksheet. Here is my function (in german):

=SVERWEIS($A1;Haus!$B$13:$K$100;7;falsch)

=VLOOKUP($A1,Haus!$B$13:$K$100,7,false)

I have lot of different worksheets and I do not want rewrite each formula by replacing Haus with the name of a different worksheet.

Is it possible to call the name from a cell? I want to have in Row 1 all worksheetnames and in row two the VLOOKUP-Function. In my imagination it should then be possible to drag the formula right and it autocompletes the formula with the right names.

A1 Haus

A2 =VLOOKUP($A1,Haus!$B$13:$K$100,7,false)

B1 Boot

B2 =VLOOKUP($A1,Haus!$B$13:$K$100,7,false)

C1 Pool etc.

I tried it with CELL("Content", A$1)&"!"$B$13:$K$100 inside the VLOOKUP-Function but it did not work as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `INDIRECT` function. Say you have your sheet name in A1 and the value that you want to look for is in A2. You could have formula in A3 like

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, INDIRECT(A1&"!$B$13:$K$100"), 7, FALSE)
```